# Having trouble finding/clicking specific images within a div class through selenium

Tags: python

Practicing web scraping through selenium by opening user's dating profiles through a dating site. I need selenium to save a href link for every profile on the page but not sure how to go about selecting it since each link is different for every profile and image. All of the profiles start with the same two div class/style which is "member-thumbnail" and "position: absolute". Thank you for any help that you can offer.

```
<div class="member-thumbnail">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <a href="/Member/Details/LvL-Up">
        <img src="//storage.com/imgcdn/m/t/502b24cb-3f75-49a1-a61a-ae80e18d86a0" class="presenceLine online">
        </a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried

Comment: photo = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[position: absolute;]').click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using more general selector as follow

```
.member-thumbnail a


photo = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.SELECTOR #GOES HERE').click()
```

So it should look something like that

```
photo = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a').click()
```

Comment: photo = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[position: absolute;]').click()

Comment: I'm sorry, what part of my code should I replace that with? Thank you.

Comment: I  really appreciate your answer just trying to figure out where to place it, soon as I am able to check, I will upvote your answer, thanks again.

Comment: Np, Update the answer, hope that helps :)